# Empty character in OCaml

Tags: ocaml

I am trying to do something fairly simple. I want to take a string such as "1,000" and return the string "1000".

Here was my attempt:

```
String.map (function x -> if x = ',' then '' else x) "1,000";;
```

however I get a compiler error saying there is a syntax error wrt `''`

Thanks for the insight!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you'd need here is a function like the following, which unfortunately is not in the standard library:

```
(* string_map_partial : (char -> char option) -> string -> string *)
let string_map_partial f s =
  let buf = String.create (String.length s) in
  let j = ref 0 in
  for i = 0 to String.length s - 1 do
    match f s.[i] with
    | None -> ()
    | Some c -> buf.[!j] <- c; incr j
  done;
  String.sub buf 0 !j
```

You can then write:

```
string_map_partial (fun c -> if c = ',' then None else Some c) "1,000"
```

(Note: I chose an imperative implementation for `string_map_partial`, because a purely functional one would require repeated string concatenation, which is fairly expensive in OCaml.)

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately, there's no character like the one you're looking for. There is a string that's 0 characters long (`""`), but there's no character that's not there at all. All characters (so to speak) are 1 character.

To solve your problem you need a more general operation than `String.map`. The essence of a map is that its input and output have the same shape but different contents. For strings this means that the input and output are strings of the same length.

Unless you really want to avoid imperative coding (which is actually a great thing to avoid, especially when starting out with OCaml), you would probably do best using `String.iter` and a buffer (from the `Buffer` module).

**Update**

The `string_map_partial` function given by Andreas Rossberg is pretty nice. Here's another implementation that uses `String.iter` and a buffer:

```
let string_map_partial f s =
    let b = Buffer.create (String.length s) in
    let addperhaps c =
        match f c with
        | None -> ()
        | Some c' -> Buffer.add_char b c'
    in
    String.iter addperhaps s;
    Buffer.contents b
```

Just an alternate implementation with different stylistic tradeoffs. Not faster, probably not slower either. It's still written imperatively (for the same reason).

Answer (score 0):

A purely functional version could be this one:

```
let string_map_partial f s =
      let n = String.length s in
      let rec map_str i acc =
          if i < n then 
              map_str (i + 1) (acc ^ (f (String.make 1 s.[i])))
          else acc 
      in map_str 0 ""
```

Which is terminal recursive, but less performant than the imperative version.